# Creé un componente React y no puedo visualizarlo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Acabo de crear un componente en una carpeta llamada **componets** este es el código que hice.

Código React.

```
   import React from 'react';

     class micomponente extends React.Component{

        render(){
        return(

    <h1>hola soy un componente</h1>
    );


  }
  }

   export default micomponente;
```

Pero cuando llamo ese componente en otro archivo llamado app.js no se muestra nada esta un el código del archivo app.js .

código React.

```
    import  React from 'react';
    import logo from './assets/images/logo.svg';
    import './assets/css/App.css';

    import micomponente from './componets/micomponente';



    function App() {


      return (
       <div className="App">
         <header className="App-header">
         <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
         </p>
    
    
    
     <section className="componentes">

     <micomponente/>
      </section> 
    
      </header>
       </div>
        );
        }

      export default App;
```

Quiero que mi componente se visualice en el archivo app.js

Answer (score 0):

El error en tu código está en que no estás importando el componente iniciando con letra mayúscula. Es decir, tu estás haciendo esto:

```
import micomponente from "./componets/micomponente";
```

Cuando en realidad deberías hacer esto:

```
import Micomponente from "./componets/micomponente";
```

Se debe a un error de sintaxis. Puedes chequear la documentación haciendo click
[aquí](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: Dos cosas: 1) La carpeta del OP se llama **componets** (lo sé, deberia ser lo otro, pero tanto en el texto de la pregunta como en su código siempre pone **componets**, por lo tanto deduzco que también la llama así en realidad).  y 2) No intentes poner negritas o cursivas en código dentro de este editor porque no se ve, y ahora quizás se cree que tiene que poner asteriscos además de la mayúscula.  Repasa tus respuestas siempre o pueden ser votadas negativamente. Saludos!